# How to setup multiple test env using cypress to test chat app?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, cypress

Is it possible to setup multiple cypress test runner to test chat apps? If yes, how? I have found on some links there is idea to test it using CasperJS and PhantomJS, but not really sure how to setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need some more information to answer this question:
1. Why do you want multiple test runners?
2. The title suggests there are multiple chat apps as well, is that correct?

What I can tell you from my own experience:
We have multiple web applications in place which all have their own test runner. Those are all executed via a Docker by Jenkins. But I can execute all tests locally on my laptop as wel (not at the same time). 
One of the web applications has 4 different test runners which all use the same test environment. But once again, run via Jenkins in a Docker.

Comment: 1. Why do you want multiple test runners? Answer: I just want to be able to test if one web app send to other web app, we will be able to assert all the result like in a test runner.
2. The title suggests there are multiple chat apps as well, is that correct? Answer: No, it's actually one app. But to test, you need 2 clients to send messages to each other.